# Count matching multiple words in the parameter from column

Tags: mysql, database

I have a table `advertisement` which has two columns, `caption`, and `description`.
So I want to find all advertisements which match the user search.
So suppose the table is having 2 records.

| id | caption | description |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Tasty Delicious | The pizza is delicious |
| 2 | New pizza | The delicious pizza is delicious |

So suppose users search for `delicious pizza`, we need a count of words each row matches.
So the output should be,

| id | caption |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 3 |
| 2 | 4 |

We need to combine `caption` and `description` and then match them with each word.
I'm able to do a single word search using below query but stuck in this

```
CHAR_LENGTH(a.caption) - CHAR_LENGTH(REPLACE(a.caption, @searchParam, SPACE(LENGTH(@searchParam)-1))) AS matchingCount
```

Any help?
I'm using MySql

Comment: *I'm able to do a single word search* Well, divide user's request to separate words, search, summarize.

Comment: It can impact performance by doing so.

Comment: What is the reason to think about performance when none solution is found...

Comment: There are different ways, I can fetch all records to java code and then do manipulations, because I don't want to choke my db for performance reasons @Akina

Comment: I think that transferring the whole data array to the client is more expensive. What is **precise** MySQL version? Does the only delimiter in the values is space char? *I'm able to do a single word search using below query* If your word to search for is a substring of a word from the value (for example, search term is "for" and the value contains the word "format") then you'll obtain incorrect output.